How to make onEachFeature updated every time GeoJSON data is updated in react-leaflet?
Using "react-leaflet": "^2.6.0" it does not call onEachFeature every time GeoJSON data is changed. Even if GeoJSON is properly changed and displayed on map I got old values in onEachFeature. Is there any workaround here?
import React from "react";
import { GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";


class GeoJsonArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     
    };

    this.onEachFeature=
      this.onEachFeature.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (
      (
        this.props.geoJsonData &&
        this.props.geoJsonData!== prevProps.geoJsonData)
    ) {
      this.props.geoJsonRef.current.leafletElement.clearLayers();
      this.props.geoJsonRef.current.leafletElement.addData(
        this.props.geoJsonData
      );
    }
  }

  // keep getting old values from first render
  onEachFeature= (feature, layer) => {
    console.log(feature)
  };

  render() {
    return (
          <GeoJSON
            ref={this.props.geoJsonRef}  
            onEachFeature={this.onEachFeature}
          />
    );
  }
}



export default GeoJsonArea ;

